# Rails Admin Creating and Using Custom Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, admin, custom-view

Is there any option for creating a Custom view in Rails Admin ?

I tried to find information about, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike devise which can generate view using

`rails g devise:views`

you cant achieve this with rails_admin as the feature is now depreciated:

`rake rails_admin:copy_views`

instead you need to style the view using the following docs

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List-view-table-styling

Comment: Thanks @Gurmukh this is not so much customizable solution but can help in some occasions. I think I will create a new controller with custom  views and then use data from rails admin models.